# why am I Getting gap between player characte collider and box collider.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I don't know why but I am getting gap between player character collider and obstacle box collider. due to this unwanted gap my player can not collide with obstacle and so I can't fire any event.

Here is image of character collider and obstacle collider and also setting of character controller.

[image: Character controller collider with obstacle collider]

[image: Character controller settings]

Comment: Just a quick try: do you have isTrigger activated on the obstacle's collider? And, if not, can you try adding it?

Comment: Yes I have two collider one is parent and second is child of this. This both have collider and trigger. It was working before made change to character controller using script. Now I have removed that code from script but still not working. @Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I just change Character controller Skin width to 0.08(default value) and it's works, gap is removed. [image: Character Controller Settings image]